# Openconnect GUI: The service providing the VPN connection was stopped

Tags: networking, kubuntu, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I've been having an issue when trying to connect to my school's vpn using the Kubuntu 19.10 openconnect gui. When I attempt to connect, I instantly get disconnected from the vpn and receive notifications saying "VPN failed to start" and "The service providing the VPN connection was stopped". When I attempt to connect to the same vpn using the openconnect cli, it works without an issue every time. Here is the output of my syslog when attempting to connect using the gui:

```
Feb 23 23:43:11 Linux-PC NetworkManager[1283]: <info>  [1582519391.1250] audit: op="connection-update" uuid="3bc81dbf-7030-4c7f-b47d-79a31121ec7c" name="New vpn connection" args="vpn.secrets" pid=2254 uid=1000 result="success"
Feb 23 23:43:11 Linux-PC NetworkManager[1283]: <info>  [1582519391.1253] vpn-connection[0x55fa199944e0,3bc81dbf-7030-4c7f-b47d-79a31121ec7c,"New vpn connection",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: starting (3)
Feb 23 23:43:11 Linux-PC NetworkManager[1283]: <info>  [1582519391.1259] manager: (vpn0): new Tun device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/12)
Feb 23 23:43:11 Linux-PC NetworkManager[1283]: /usr/sbin/openconnect: symbol lookup error: /usr/sbin/openconnect: undefined symbol: openconnect_has_tss2_blob_support, version OPENCONNECT_5_5
Feb 23 23:43:11 Linux-PC NetworkManager[1283]: <warn>  [1582519391.1557] vpn-connection[0x55fa199944e0,3bc81dbf-7030-4c7f-b47d-79a31121ec7c,"New vpn connection",0]: VPN plugin: failed: connect-failed (1)
Feb 23 23:43:11 Linux-PC NetworkManager[1283]: <info>  [1582519391.1558] vpn-connection[0x55fa199944e0,3bc81dbf-7030-4c7f-b47d-79a31121ec7c,"New vpn connection",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopping (5)
Feb 23 23:43:11 Linux-PC NetworkManager[1283]: <info>  [1582519391.1558] vpn-connection[0x55fa199944e0,3bc81dbf-7030-4c7f-b47d-79a31121ec7c,"New vpn connection",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
Feb 23 23:43:11 Linux-PC NetworkManager[1283]: <info>  [1582519391.1576] vpn-connection[0x55fa199944e0,3bc81dbf-7030-4c7f-b47d-79a31121ec7c,"New vpn connection",0]: VPN service disappeared
```

When I try to connect to the same vpn using another PC with the the same OS and up to date packages as my current PC, the vpn connection works through the GUI without a problem which leads me to believe there is some configuration issue on my current PC.

Any suggestions for how to fix this are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up fixing this issue by building the latest version of `openconnect` from their github page and then manually installing `network-manager-openconnect` from the .deb file using

`apt-get download network-manager-openconnect`

followed by force installing it with

`sudo dpkg --force-all -i network-manager-openconnect_1.2.4-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb`

I had to do this because every time I tried installing `network-manager-openconnect`, whether it be before or after building and installing openconnect, apt would remove openconnect and install an older version of openconnect that would not work with the gui. Once I did all of the above commands, I was able to connect to all of my VPN connections through the GUI.

Comment: I found using [this PPA repository](https://launchpad.net/~dwmw2/+archive/ubuntu/openconnect) (linked from [their Packages page](https://www.infradead.org/openconnect/packages.html)) an easy way to get a recent version. Also, the issue persisted until I restarted the machine.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make following changes:

1. `sudo ufw disable`
2. `sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf`

Add the following at the bottom of the file:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

You NEED to restart!

After the restart, all VPN connections work straight away!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but unfortunately this did not fix the issue.

Comment: Killing the firewall and ipv6 doesn't seem too great a suggestion